# SharePoint prompts for credentials again and again for 1 user only

Tags: authentication, 401

Ours is a SharePoint 2010 environment. Authentication is based on LDAP.
Since few days a user is not able to login into the intranet application. He gets prompt for login again and again.

I checked for permission for this user. He has permission

Read, Limited Access
Given through the "Home Visitors" group.
Read, Limited Access
Given through the "All Authenticated Users" group.
Read, Limited Access
Given through the "xyz" group.
Limited Access
Given through the "abc" group.

Not getting links on google which mention about specific user. 
Kindly advise.

Thank you

Comment: Check whether user is able to login to Intranet application from another machine.

Comment: I presume you have ruled out the device and tested the account on a virgin browser/device

Comment: Thanks P S and Thanks Danny. On the same machine when i try to login. It works. I am system administrator.
Any Specific step i need to do  trace the issue.